# Use wordpress function in file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress Child Theme and I add php file to this child theme. Also I want to use wordpress function in this file  ( I want to show header, menu and footer )

So I try

```
<?php

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

?>
```

Also I try to add header and footer

```
<?php get_header();?>

//my content

<?php get_footer();
```

But it seems it cant load all css/js files and page have bad styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Omnisite , If you want to use wordpress function in separate file the make use of wp-blog-header.php like below

```
require( ABSPATH . 'wp-blog-header.php' );
```

And if you want to use template function like get_header() and get_footer() then declare that file as a template file like

```
 <?php 
/*
  Template Name: XYZ
*/

get_header();

//my content

get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WP functions in a seperate PHP file, all you have to do is include wp-blog-header.php. Like:

Make sure you have the correct path before wp-blog-header.php.